# Pass touch events from UIView on top of UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, gesture, touches

I'm trying to build a custom table view with a UIView overlaying it. I'm trying to recognize a special gesture on the regular UIView, specifically a pan gesture that takes a double tap to activate it (tap and hold, then pan).

I currently have a custom UITableViewController, as well as a custom UIView. I'd like to try to keep it as a UITableViewController instead of a UITableView inside a UIViewController for compatibility reasons (easy replacing of existing UITableViewControllers).

I can get a double tap and pan no problem, but the issue is I can no longer actually SELECT a row in the table view. I can scroll within the table, but actual selections do not work.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to retain all taps, swipes, and regular events in any custom table view cells (for example, Clear or Mailbox where you can swipe left or right to activate a specific action).

I know that I can get the table view cell from the method `indexPathForRowAtPoint:`
from the table view, but that will only allow me to select the toggle.

I've also tried to override the touches began like this:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
}
```

as well as other associated events, and have confirmed that nextResponder is the custom UITableViewController, but have not been able to do anything.

I checked into a bunch of other posts but no solutions have worked for me. Some other things I have tried are:

- Adding a single tap gesture recognizer and forwarding it to the UITableViewController

  ```
  [_containingTableViewController gestureRecognizerShouldBegin: tapGesture];
  ```
- Implemented different gesture recognizer delegates

  ```
  -(BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:  (UITouch *)touch{
      return ( touch.tapCount >= 2 );
  }
  ```

  As well as both YES and NO for:

  ```
  -(BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
  ```

Also, on the table view I've tried setting `canCancelContentTouches` but neither value works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have tried quite a bunch but just can't get it!

I may be able to post the full project on GitHub if it really needs to be done, but I'll have to clean it up a tad first.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I didn't understand your trouble, so I am not sure if it can helps you, but you can use the method `setUserInteractionEnabled`* to `FALSE/NO` of the `UIView`, `UITableView`, etc to disable any type of events on it.